# parameters, Html checkbox takes in elm

Tags: elm

This is the view snippet taken from elm checkbox [examples](http://elm-lang.org/examples/checkboxes) -

```
view address model =
  div [] <|
    span [toStyle model] [text "Hello, how are yo?"]
    :: br [] []
    :: checkbox address model.red Red "red"
    ++ checkbox address model.underline Underline "underline"
    ++ checkbox address model.bold Bold "bold"

checkbox : Address Action -> Bool -> (Bool -> Action) -> String -> List Html
checkbox address isChecked tag name =
  [ input
      [ type' "checkbox"
      , checked isChecked
      , on "change" targetChecked (Signal.message address << tag)
      ]
      []
  , text name
  , br [] []
  ]
```

1) I understand, `double colons` and `double plus` are for concatenating lists? How are they different from each other?

2) In the `checkbox` function in this line, `(Signal.message address << tag)`, what does `tag` unbind to? Is it `Red` (or) `red`? What is this argument used for?

3) What is the type of argument does the `address` function take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

1. double colon [`(::)`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/List#::) adds a single element to the start of a list.
   double plus [`(++)`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Basics#++) concatenates two lists.
2. `tag` would be equal to `Red` in the when `checkbox` is called from `checkbox address model.red Red "red"`. `Red` is a function from `Bool` to `Action`. It wraps the event of the check box in this data constructor so that later in the `update` function, you can distinguish the event of that check box from the events of the other check boxes.
3. `address` is not a function. It has type `Address Action`, meaning it holds the address of a mailbox that can receive `Action` messages. This "mailbox" is not visible in the code, it's used internally by `StartApp`, which is used in the `main` function.

## Code references

To keep this question useful even if the linked example changes, these are the relevant code portions I'm referring to:

The `update` function:

```
update action model =
  case action of
    Red bool ->
        { model | red <- bool }

    Underline bool ->
        { model | underline <- bool }

    Bold bool ->
        { model | bold <- bool }
```

The `Action` type:

```
type Action
  = Red Bool
  | Underline Bool
  | Bold Bool
```

The `main` function:

```
main =
  StartApp.start { model = initialModel, view = view, update = update }
```